# Django order by Min Distance to a list of points

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, postgis

I want to get a queryset of all Jobs that are within a given distance to at least one of the many provided locations, order them by the minimum distance, and do not show duplicate jobs.

```
from django.db import models
from cities.models import City    

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

If there is only one point I could do this as:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
point = Point(x, y, srid=4326)  
Job.objects.filter(cities__location__dwithin=(point, dist)) \
           .annotate(distance=Distance("cities__location", point) \
           .order_by('distance')
```

but when I have many points I build out a Q expression for the filter but am unsure of a clean way to annotate the Min distance of the Job to all points

```
query = Q()
for point in points:
    query |= Q(cities__location__dwithin=(point, dist))
Job.objects.filter(query).annotate(distance=Min(...)).order_by('distance')
```

FYI using postgres 12.1 with PostGIS extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = Q()
distances = []
for point in points:
    query |= Q(cities__location__dwithin=(point, dist))
    distances.append(Distance("cities__location", point))

# LEAST requires 2 or more expressions, MIN works for single expression
if len(distances) == 1:
    MIN_FUNC = Min
else:
    MIN_FUNC = Least

Job.objects.filter(query).annotate(distance=MIN_FUNC(*distances)).order_by('distance')
```

- `MIN` is an aggregation function that takes a single expression, such as a column name, and reduces multiple inputs to a single output value
- `LEAST` is a conditional expression that functions by selecting the smallest value from a list of any number of expressions

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#min
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#least